# Issue when copying a ArrayList to an Array. Elements are not being preserved

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, collections, arraylist

I'm experiencing an issue with ArrayList.ToArray where it seems to be reallocating some of the references that are stored in the ArrayList when I convert it to an array. I have an ArrayList of references which are used as keys in a HashTable. At one point the ArrayList is copied to an Array using the line below:

```
destination.Items = newItems.ToArray(typeof(MyItem)) as MyItem[];
```

The way I see it references in the target array should have been preserved from the source ArrayList but doesn't always occur. In some instances when I use the references in the target arrays to do a lookup in the HashTable it fails.

But If I use the code below to explicitly copy the items to the source array than the lookups succeed 100% of the times.

```
MyItem[] Items = destination.Items;
Array.Resize(ref Items, newItems.Count);   //First I resize to receive all the elements

int i = 0;
foreach (MyItem newItem in newItems)
{
    Items[i++] = newItem;
}
```

Is there anything being done under the covers by ArrayList.ToArray (reallocation for instance)  which could cause the elements to be re-created such that the HashTable lookup would fail ?

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Resizing arrays does not sound good to me. I would prefer using List<T> instead...

Comment: Which .net framework version you're in? Post your hashtable code also, What is the key of it?

Comment: @MUG4N Agreed. But I dont have that option, the Array is part of a library

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, I'm using .Net 4.5. As for the HashTable code, I'm just using System.Collections.HashTable with an instance of MyItem as the key.

Comment: @TomKoberle Good, Is your `MyItem` mutable? I mean do you change its fields after adding it to `HashTable`?

Comment: btw Are you struck with `ArrayList` and `HashTable`? I'll suggest you to use `List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`

Comment: The MyItem instances are not modified after they get added to the HashTable. I agree that the generics vesrion of List and Dictionary are better but unfortunately the instances I am using are created inside a library so I dont have access to the source code

Comment: Perhaps there's is a conversion issue (e.g. items in the ListArray are not purely of type MyItem). Also, if MyItem is of type struct the elements will be copied by value, not reference.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make sense, unless there's more on this story. For example, if there are other threads changing values, or if you are storing other types that are not compatible, etc.

Can you change your ArrayList to List? That could resolve the issue if it's a bug in ArrayList.

However I would recommend that you create a temp hack in your code so that you always compare all the items of the original list vs all the items on the returned array. If both collections don't match 100%,then dump both Into a log file (dump both the values AND some Metadata such as the total elements, type of the elements, etc)